# How to change Jenkins Build History text without changing Build Description

Tags: jenkins

Our Build Descriptions are rather lengthy:

[image: Lengthy Build Description]

I don't want that lengthy text in the build history though.  Is there a way to change the Build History Text WITHOUT changing the Build Description?

[image: Build History Text]

I tried [Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) but the examples change the badges, or the text next to the date, not the actual text that is in the Build History?

Is there a way to change the Build History text WITHOUT changing Build Description?

Answer (score 0):

try [the description setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin)

Comment: that changes the description of the build, not the build history text.  I can't change the description of the build because it has a lot of useful information.  With all that text of the build description, it muddles the build history.  That is why I want to change the text of the build history and NOT the build description.

Answer (score 0):

In your `JENKINS_HOME/jobs/JOB_NAME/builds/` directory there are all the builds you have done.
Each build has a `build.xml` file which contains a `<description>` tag, try to edit this and reload jenkins from disk, you will see the magic!